# large sql server query performance optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in eCommerce search module. I wrote a query for that but the query is very long and it is taking too much of time to load the data. How can I optimize this query?

[SQL Query](http://developmentasstaing.mindtosite.com/Content/File/SqlQuery.txt)

[Execution Plan](http://developmentasstaing.mindtosite.com/Content/File/ExceutionPlan.txt)

Comment: _Nobody_ is going to sift through that gigantic XML execution plan and give you an answer.  You should do some legwork first and then ask us for suggestions.

Comment: `The text submitted is larger than 2MB. We cannot accept plans larger than 2MB at this time. Sorry. (⌣_⌣”)` Not my fault but even PasteThePlan refuses to treat your problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

Problem comes from your 5th query. 57% of the cost is here.
Insert into #tempdata "takes" 70% of the sub-query.

But considering how complex the query is,
I would only suggest to simplify it or split it into multiple queries.

Also consider running the query and recover the actual query plan instead of the estimated one.

First of all, narrow your analysis into this 5th query.